# instance variables in @interface; header vs implementation

Tags: objective-c, header-files, instance-variables

Is there any difference between declaring a private instance variable in the header vs declaring it in the implementation?

in TestObj.h

```
@interface TestObj : NSObject
{
    int test;
}
@end
```

vs in TestObj.m

```
@interface TestObj()
{
    int test;
}
@end
```

Both seem equivalent to me, is there any actual difference between declaring an instance variable in the header vs in the implementation, if not which is preferred?  The `@interface` within the implementation file just seems like a way to declare private properties, does it have any other purpose outside that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The preference is generally to place private instance variables and properties in the private class extension (in the .m) and leave the public interface file (.h) for those properties and methods that are truly part of the public interface.

It helps isolate implementation details from the public interface and makes everything much cleaner. It also ensures that external classes do not inadvertently alter the private variables of this class.

See [Class Extensions Extend the Internal Implementation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3).

Comment: So to clarify besides organization there is no functional difference between the two?

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia Correct, no functional difference within the `TestObj` class, but ensures that external classes do not inadvertently mess around with private variables. That strikes me as more than just an "organizational" detail, but rather critical in making robust code.

Comment: There is one functional difference: ivars in the class's `@interface` are `@protected` by default, and ivars in a class extension `@interface` or in `@implementation` are `@private` by default.

Answer (score 7):

Greg Parker's comment on the accepted answer is the best answer here:

> There is one functional difference: ivars in the class's `@interface` are `@protected` by default, and ivars in a class extension @interface or in `@implementation` are `@private` by default.

Comment: So say you are making an SDK with a private class extension in its own TestObj_Private.h, you would then need to declare the ivar as @protected ?