# how make static cells in tableview controller objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellIdent = @"mycal";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdent];
    yes=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    no=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

  /*  if(cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdent];


    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text=[mathcal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if([arSelectedRows containsObject:indexPath]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }*/

    int firstNumber=0,lastNumber = 0,calculation,ans=0;
    int todisplay= [self getRandomNumberBetween:0 to:1];
    NSLog(@"to display:::%d",todisplay);
    if(finalanswers==nil)
    {
        finalanswers=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    [finalanswers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:todisplay]];
        NSLog(@"finalanswers::::%@",finalanswers);
    calculation=[self getRandomNumberBetween:0 to:3];
    NSLog(@"cat value %@",mathCat);
    if ([mathCat isEqualToString:@"Easy"]) {
        firstNumber = [self getRandomNumberBetween:1 to:9];
        lastNumber = [self getRandomNumberBetween:1 to:9];
       // NSLog(@"firstNumber %d lastnumber %d",firstNumber,lastNumber);
    }
    else if ([mathCat isEqualToString:@"Medium"]){
        firstNumber = [self getRandomNumberBetween:10 to:99];
        lastNumber = [self getRandomNumberBetween:10 to:99];
       // NSLog(@"firstNumber %d lastnumber %d",firstNumber,lastNumber);
    }
    else if ([mathCat isEqualToString:@"Hard"]){
        firstNumber = [self getRandomNumberBetween:100 to:999];
        lastNumber = [self getRandomNumberBetween:100 to:999];
       // NSLog(@"firstNumber %d lastnumber %d",firstNumber,lastNumber);
    }

   // NSLog(@"calc value is -->  %@",[mathcal objectAtIndex:calculation]);




    //cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d+%d=%d",firstNumber,lastNumber,todisplay];
    if (todisplay==0) {
        if (calculation==0) {
            ans=firstNumber+lastNumber;
            answer=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d + %d=%d",firstNumber,lastNumber,ans];

            cell.textLabel.text=answer;
            return cell;
        }
        else if (calculation==1){
            ans=firstNumber-lastNumber;
            answer=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d - %d=%d",firstNumber,lastNumber,ans];

            cell.textLabel.text=answer;
            return cell;
        }
        else if (calculation==2){
            ans=firstNumber*lastNumber;
            answer=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d * %d=%d",firstNumber,lastNumber,ans];

            cell.textLabel.text=answer;
            return cell;
        }
        else if (calculation==3){
            ans=firstNumber/lastNumber;
            answer=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d / %d=%d",firstNumber,lastNumber,ans];

            cell.textLabel.text=answer;
            return cell;
        }

    }
    else if (todisplay==1){
        int ans=[self getRandomNumberBetween:10 to:50];
        answer=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d+%d=%d",firstNumber,lastNumber,ans];
        cell.textLabel.text=answer;
        return cell;
    }

      return cell;
}
-(int)getRandomNumberBetween:(int)from to:(int)to {

    return (int)from + arc4random() % (to-from+1);
}
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I am generating random questions, but when i scroll up and comes back, the questions are changing. I want to make them static. only if the user exits from the application or finishes the game and starts a new game only then it should generate different questions

Answer (score 1):

You are getting random questions because every time you scroll and a new cell becomes visible, you throw a dice and generate another question.

You should generate all the random questions beforehand, instead of in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

So you should generate an array of random numbers that refers to your question and answer array at `viewDidLoad`, same number as the cells in your table. Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, access the number in that array and configure the cell to display that question.

This way you will have non-changing questions!

The code is a little bit messy, but essentially, we want to move the question generating logic into `viewDidLoad`, create an array to hold those things, then read it from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  // GENERATING RANDOM QUESTIONS
  firstNumbers = [NSMutableArray array];
  lastNumbers = [NSMutableArray array];

  for (int i = 0; i < [tv numberOfRowsInSection:0]; i++) {
    int firstNumber, lastNumber;
    if ([mathCat isEqualToString:@"Easy"]) {
      firstNumber = [self getRandomNumberBetween:1 to:9];
      lastNumber = [self getRandomNumberBetween:1 to:9];
      // NSLog(@"firstNumber %d lastnumber %d",firstNumber,lastNumber);
    }
    else if ([mathCat isEqualToString:@"Medium"]){
      firstNumber = [self getRandomNumberBetween:10 to:99];
      lastNumber = [self getRandomNumberBetween:10 to:99];
      // NSLog(@"firstNumber %d lastnumber %d",firstNumber,lastNumber);
    }
    else if ([mathCat isEqualToString:@"Hard"]){
      firstNumber = [self getRandomNumberBetween:100 to:999];
      lastNumber = [self getRandomNumberBetween:100 to:999];
      // NSLog(@"firstNumber %d lastnumber %d",firstNumber,lastNumber);
    }

    [firstNumbers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:firstNumber]];
    [lastNumbers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:lastNumber]];
  }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  NSString *cellIdent = @"mycal";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdent];
  yes=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
  no=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

  int firstNumber= [firstNumbers[indexPath.row] intValue];
  int lastNumber = [lastNumbers[indexPath.row] intValue];

  int calculation, ans=0;
  int todisplay= [self getRandomNumberBetween:0 to:1];
  NSLog(@"to display:::%d",todisplay);
  if(finalanswers==nil) {
    finalanswers=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  }

  [finalanswers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:todisplay]];
  NSLog(@"finalanswers::::%@",finalanswers);
  calculation=[self getRandomNumberBetween:0 to:3];
  NSLog(@"cat value %@",mathCat);


  // NSLog(@"calc value is -->  %@",[mathcal objectAtIndex:calculation]);

  // REMOVED GENERATION TO VIEW DID LOAD

  //cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d+%d=%d",firstNumber,lastNumber,todisplay];
  if (todisplay==0) {
    if (calculation==0) {
      ans=firstNumber+lastNumber;
      answer=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d + %d=%d",firstNumber,lastNumber,ans];

      cell.textLabel.text=answer;
      return cell;
    }
    else if (calculation==1){
      ans=firstNumber-lastNumber;
      answer=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d - %d=%d",firstNumber,lastNumber,ans];

      cell.textLabel.text=answer;
      return cell;
    }
    else if (calculation==2){
      ans=firstNumber*lastNumber;
      answer=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d * %d=%d",firstNumber,lastNumber,ans];

      cell.textLabel.text=answer;
      return cell;
    }
    else if (calculation==3){
      ans=firstNumber/lastNumber;
      answer=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d / %d=%d",firstNumber,lastNumber,ans];

      cell.textLabel.text=answer;
      return cell;
    }

  }
  else if (todisplay==1){
    int ans=[self getRandomNumberBetween:10 to:50];
    answer=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d+%d=%d",firstNumber,lastNumber,ans];
    cell.textLabel.text=answer;
    return cell;
  }

  return cell;
}

-(int)getRandomNumberBetween:(int)from to:(int)to {
  return (int)from + arc4random() % (to-from+1);
}
```

Note, I declared `firstNumbers`, `lastNumbers` as `NSMutableArray` in the header, as well as assumed you have a reference to your `tableView`, named `tv`. Finally, I assumed you only have a single section in your table. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please change the code and show it to me? i even tried that. But it's not working for me. It's throwing an error

Comment: Added the code. It's a little messy and I'm working with less information that I can here. Made a few assumptions. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the code. I will check on it now.

Comment: int firstNumber= [firstNumber[indexPath.row] intValue];
 it's throwing an error in this statement, "Subscripted value is not an array, pointer or vector. What changes do i need to make

Comment: Its supposed to be `firstNumbers[indexPath.row]`. You are taking out your first number from the previously generated array.

Comment: it's displaying an error, use of undeclared identifier firstNumbers and advised to change it to firstNumber.. In the statement     "int firstNumber= [firstNumbers[indexPath.row] intValue];"

Comment: Yeah, I declared extra parameters. See the last paragraph.

Comment: And even this statement is throwing an error "firstNumbers = [NSMutableArray array];"  when i change the code to     NSMutableArray *firstNumbers = [NSMutableArray array];
it's not throwing an error. Is their anything wrong I making

Comment: Yes, you didn't declare the parameters in the header as I suggested you should...

You need somewhere to store the data. Therefore you need to declare new variables...

Comment: In the header as in? In the (void) viewDidLoad method?

Comment: No. That would be a local variable. You need to declare an instance variable. Find either the first or the second [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616709/instance-variables-in-interface-header-vs-implementation) and put those names in.

Comment: I did include it in the same way in .h file. still the error remains same

Comment: Can you please help with that

Comment: . h file                                                                                                   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MathViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NSMutableArray* mathcal;
    NSMutableArray *arSelectedRows;
    NSMutableArray* answer;
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *firstCountDownLabel1;
    NSTimer *firstCountDownTimer1;
    bool timerActive;
    int secondsCount;
    NSMutableArray *finalanswers;
    int firstNumbers;
    int lastNumbers;
}

Comment: @interface MathViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NSMutableArray *finalanswers;
    int firstNumbers;
    int lastNumbers;
}

Comment: Change `firstNumbers` and `lastNumbers` types to `NSMutableArray`...you can't just copy the code, you have to understand what I'm doing here to solve the problem...

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    
    return 200;
}    It showing error index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'